# Error in CreateInstance() while dynamically creating object of concrete type in Factory Pattern

Tags: .net-core, design-patterns, dependency-injection, factory-pattern

I am actually new to design patterns and trying to implement factory pattern with .NET Core.

I tried to see couple of posts related to factory pattern and trying to implement it, I have added the concrete types in the config and reading it as dictionary in my code -

My Factory Interface -

```cs
public interface IEmpFactory
{
    public BaseEmployee CreateEmployeeType<EmpType>()
        where EmpType : BaseEmployee, new();
}
```

Implementation -

```cs
public class EmpFactoryImpl : IEmpFactory
{
    public BaseEmployee CreateEmployeeType<EmpType>()
        where EmpType: BaseEmployee, new()
    {
        return new EmpType();
    }
}
```

Below are my services which are using the Factory as dependency -

```cs
public interface IEmpService
{
    public string GetEmployeeBonus();
}

public class ContractEmpService : IEmpService
{
    IEmpFactory _empFactory;

    public ContractEmpService(IEmpFactory empFactory) =>
        _empFactory = empFactory;
        
    private BaseEmployee CreateMyEmployee() =>
         _empFactory.CreateEmployeeType<ContractEmp>();

    public string GetEmployeeBonus() =>
        return CreateMyEmployee().GetBonus();
}

public class PermEmpService : IEmpService
{
    private readonly IEmpFactory _empFactory;

    public PermEmpService(IEmpFactory empFactory) =>
        _empFactory = empFactory;

    private BaseEmployee CreateMyEmployee() =>
        _empFactory.CreateEmployeeType<PermEmp>();

    public string GetEmployeeBonus() =>
        CreateMyEmployee().GetBonus();
}
```

Added these concrete types in the config -

```json
  "ConfigurationProps": {
    "EmpServices": {
      "PermEmp": "SimpleFactoryWithoutSwitchCase.Service.PermEmpService",
      "ContractEmp": "SimpleFactoryWithoutSwitchCase.Service.ContractEmpService"
    }
  }
```

Created the class to create a instance of the concrete type based on the type i.e, `PermEmp` or `ContractEmp` dynamically -

```cs
public class EmployeeTypeRouter : IEmployeeTypeRouter
{
    private readonly ConfigurationProps _props;

    public EmployeeTypeRouter(ConfigurationProps props)
    {
        _props = props;
    }

    public IEmpService GetInstance(string key)
    {
        string className = _props.EmpServices
            .Where(k => k.Key.Equals(key)).FirstOrDefault().Value;

        Type t = Type.GetType(className);

        return (IEmpService)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    }
}
```

This is my calling method -

```cs
[HttpGet(Name = "GetEmployeeBonus")]
public string Get()
{
    string type = "PermEmp";
    IEmpService empService = _empRouter.GetInstance(type);

    return empService.GetEmployeeBonus();
}
```

based on the type passed here i want to fetch the concrete type and call the method.

**I am getting the error like this on `CreateInstance` method** -

> System.MissingMethodException: `Cannot dynamically create an instance of type 'SimpleFactoryWithoutSwitchCase.Service.PermEmpService'. Reason: No parameterless constructor defined.'

Which is very clear, but I don't want to create a parameterless constructor.

*Since I am registering the dependencies in .NET Core, do I need to pass it again here? (which does not make sense for me)*

Any help is really appreciated or if you feel I am doing something wrong please let me know.

Comment: Please show all this code as *text* - it's much, much easier to read, as well as being easier to copy for answers. But fundamentally, you're calling `Activator.CreateInstance(Type)`, which is documented as "Creates an instance of the specified type using that type's parameterless constructor." But there isn't a parameterless constructor. `Activator.CreateInstance` doesn't know anything about dependency injection - you need to ask the DI framework for dependencies.

Comment: "you need to ask the DI framework for dependencies" -  This is what my question is how i can do this ?

Comment: It's entirely possible that injecting an `IServiceProvider` into your `EmployeeTypeRouter` is the way to go, although that's *sometimes* considered an anti-pattern. To be honest, if this is all configuration-based, I'd try to inject the right implementations while setting up DI rather than during the request itself.

Comment: Does that mean adding the conditions in the DI to inject the required implementations at runtime ?  If so, in this case its only EmployeeService there can be many more implementations possible so adding conditions to each is tedious process.

Comment: I mean that you can use `Type.GetType` during ConfigureServices to get the right type from your configuration, and inject that appropriately. But comment threads really aren't meant for this sort of back and forth - I suggest you try either of the options I've suggested already. (I'd argue that given you understand why the Activator.CreateInstance approach doesn't work, you could simplify the question to avoid going into details about it.)

Answer (score 0):

Your `EmployeeTypeRouter` class tries to replicate the creation process that your DI Container can do more eloquently. So instead of calling `Activator.CreateInstance`, forward the resolution to the DI Container.

This means the following things:

1. Register all known `IEmpService` at startup.
2. Resolve the expected type from the `IServiceProvider` from inside the `EmployeeTypeRouter`.

In other words, change the startup code to the following:

```cs
var dictionary = props.EmpServices
    .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => Type.GetType(p.Value));

foreach (string pair in dictionary)
{
    services.AddTransient(pair.Value);
}

services.AddTransient<IEmployeeTypeRouter, EmployeeTypeRouter>();

services.AddTransient<Func<string, IEmpService>>(sp =>
    key => (IEmpService)sp.GetRequiredService(dictionary[key]));
```

And change `EmployeeTypeRouter` to the following:

```cs
public class EmployeeTypeRouter : IEmployeeTypeRouter
{
    private readonly Func<string, IEmpService> _factory;

    public EmployeeTypeRouter(Func<string, IEmpService> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public IEmpService GetInstance(string key) =>
        _factory.Invoke(key);
}
```

In the previous code snippet, `EmployeeTypeRouter` makes use of the `Func<string, IEmpService>` delegate, which functions as factory. Under the covers the delegate calls back into the `IServiceProvider`.

There are of course several ways to skin a cat. You could also move some of the startup logic into `EmployeeTypeRouter`, or even  remove the `IEmployeeTypeRouter` altogether and let application code depend directly on `Func<string, IEmpService>` delegate.

Comment: Thanks a lot Steven. This is exactly what i was looking for, one small question - Can i access the value i.e, "key" in my Startup class which is coming from my UI ?

Comment: Hi @AbhijithNayak. I misread your question, which caused me to write an answer that was of no use to you. I now redone my answer in its entirety. Please reread it and see if its now of any use to you.

Comment: Thanks for the update Steven, after updating the code you have given, i am still getting the issue for ContractEmp type not added in the service provider   "No service for type 'SimpleFactoryWithoutSwitchCase.Service.ContractEmpService' has been registered"  even though dynamically it added.                                                                      This error i am getting while creating an instance of the service from EmployeeController.

Comment: Hi Abhijith. I made an error. See my update.

Comment: Unfortunately, i am facing the same issue - "InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'SimpleFactoryWithoutSwitchCase.Service.IEmpService' while attempting to activate 'SimpleFactoryWithStratergyPattern.Controllers.EmployeeController'.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. You might want to debug through the code to see what gets registered and what gets resolved by the `EmployeeTypeRouter`.